# What does "willingly surrender" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The context is:

"person 1: Can you hug me close?

person 2: So tight you willingly surrender your breath."

what does it mean?

Comment: To *surrender* something is to ***give it up, go without it***. And *willingly* here means ***gladly, deliberately*** (as opposed to, say, ***reluctantly***). Your example is rather weird, because normally we'd expect *Please hug me so tight you take **my** breath away* (so tight ***I*** can't breath), but in your case the addressee is being asked to hug the speaker so hard ***the addressee*** can't breathe. But I'd ignore that "oddity" - most likely the writer just hasn't thought through exactly what he's trying to convey.

Comment: Oh, it is a dialog: person 1: Can you hug me close?  person 2: So tight you willingly surrender your breath. in this way makes sense?

Comment: As I explained, it doesn't make much sense. I'm not even sure it's physically *possible* for someone to wrap their arms around something (*anything* - another person, a lamppost, or whatever) so hard ***they*** can't breathe! But the meanings of ***willingly*** and ***surrender*** here are quite straightforward. Whatever - I don't know where you got your text from, but it looks very unlikely to me that your "person1 / person2" edit accurately reflects the context.

Comment: Thank you, Monica. It is a real conversation I had with a native speaker (I am person 1). So, if it is odd for you, imagine how it is for me :)

Comment: Now I'm *really* confused! You had this conversation (i.e. - you were a participant), and you're asking ***us*** what it means?

Comment: yes, because it was an online conversation...

Comment: You say you were "person1", but I can't really understand why you would send someone the text message  *Can you hug me close?*, since in context that would presumably be physically impossible. But all I can say is person2's reply doesn't make sense. He knows nothing about how "willing" you might be.

Comment: Have you looked up "willingly" and "surrender" in a dictionary? What does it say about these words? Please kindly edit your question to include the definitions.